# Help with Vehicle model?

Tags: car, automotive-design

[image: ThreeWheelCar]
Need help in identifying this 3 wheeled model.
Thanks!

Comment: The deathmobile would be fitting from the look of it.

Comment: It might very well be a one-off project.  I've seen similar vehicles made using a motorcycle with the front portion removed and then grafted onto the front suspension of a 4-wheeled vehicle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this your picture, in Prague, from 2014? Context ***really*** helps with these types of questions.

Comment: Also, for a three wheeler, having the two tires up front provides a LOT of stability. The vehicle shown is reminiscent of a [Polaris Slingshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_Slingshot), but is not one. In the Slingshot, the driver sits a LOT closer to the rear wheel where there's a storage location in the front (yes, a "frunk"). A little more practical than the one pictured (if you can call any of them "practical").

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Notably the Slingshot has the engine in front of the driver between the front wheels.  The photo appears to show the drivers legs where the engine might be and I suspect the engine is located between the driver's seat back and the rear wheel.

Comment: @jwh20 - Agreed. Wikipedia states the Slingshot has been around since 2014, with production being here in the US. It doesn't say if it's exported, but even then, I really doubt it would have been exported that early on in its life. I wouldn't doubt the three wheeler in the image is a one-off or home grown type situation.

Comment: @Paulster would the British call that a "froot" or a "bonoot"?